# Delete row if results are not listed inside database (Array-loop)

Tags: php, sql

**Situation:** List of question will be read from the database and display inside a table. I can add new row or remove row that I wanted. The data that will be submitted will be store using an array. Update and insert are works perfectly as shown below.

**Problems:** If user delete some rows on the table, how can I delete those data inside the database.

Sorry for bad grammar/english. Thanks for helping!

Html code:

```
<table class="msgBox" id="simulator2">
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th class="msgSubject">QUESTION</th>
</tr>
<?php
    $qry="SELECT ques_item, ques_id FROM log_question WHERE eva_id = '$action'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $i=1;
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $eQuesID = $rows['ques_id'];
        $eQues = $rows['ques_item'];
?>
<tr class="table-row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
    <td class="dataBox"><input type="text" name="eQues[]" value="<?php echo $eQues; ?>" /><input type="hidden" name="eQuesID[]" value="<?php echo $eQuesID; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<?php $i++; 
    } $tempCount = $i-1;
?>
</table>
<br />
<center>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('simulator2')" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('simulator2')" />
</center>
```

Php code:

```
$a = 0;
foreach (array_combine($eQues, $eQuesID) as $eQuest => $eQuestID){
    if ($a < $tempCount){ // Update Question
        $sql="UPDATE log_question SET ques_item='$eQuest' WHERE ques_id='$eQuestID'";
        $test=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if(!$test) {
            echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
            exit();
        }
    } else { //Insert New Question
        $newsql="INSERT INTO log_question VALUES('', '$eID', '$eQuest')";
        $newtest=mysqli_query($con, $newsql);
        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if(!$newtest){
            echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
            exit();
        }
    } $a++;
}
```

Comment: you need to use ajax to delete row.

Comment: No better place to start than the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html

Comment: @RuchishParikh is there any other solutions rather than ajax? I dont know how to use ajax. :(

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know how the sql delete works =.=" the problem is if the user delete rows on table (html code), how can I delete the the rest of selected data which not inside the array.